# what does mean "SQL Error: 30000, SQLState: XSAI3"?

Tags: hibernate, derby, javadb

I'm using javadb/derbydb 10.5.3.0 with hibernate 3.5-Final I get this error at the end of EM initialisation :

```
4427 [SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 30000, SQLState: XSAI3
4427 [SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Feature not implemented.
```

SQL Error 30000 doesn't seem to be documented 
http://developers.sun.com/docs/javadb/10.3.3.0/ref/ref-single.html#rrefexcept71493

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feature not implemented is often used for SQL optional features which Derby doesn't yet support. Can you identify from your logs which statement resulted in this error? If it's not easy to track down the offending statement, try turning on Derby statement-level logging (-Dderby.language.logStatementText=true, I think) and then look in the derby.log file for more information about which SQL statement caused the error.

If you can post the exact SQL statement which encountered this error, maybe we can offer more suggestions.